# I keep getting this when typing in nslookup. I`m also having problems connect desktops to domain

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, domain-controller, nslookup

I`m trying to connect a server my current domain. So far I just have server 2003 on the system with no roles. This server will act as a backup or a application server in the future.

My other server 192.168.52.183 is acting as a AD,dns, terminal server and is running other computer programs works fine.

When try to connect to the domain i keep getting cant find domain message..

When typing nslook i`m getting this error...

could this be the problem.. how do i fix this??

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]
(C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.APLUS>nslookup
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Can't find server name for address 107.7.59.210: Timed out
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  107.7.59.210

>Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]
(C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft Corp.

Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]
(C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft Corp.



>Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]
(C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.APLUS>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Server
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : Home.aplus.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Home.aplus.com
                                       aplus.com

Ethernet adapter Externel:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom BCM5708C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS
 VBD Client) #45
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-18-8B-4E-AF-B4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.52.183
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.52.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 107.7.59.210
                                       207.230.75.50
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.APLUS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be setting the DNS to look at the AD server not at the other IP (Or adding records to that DNS Server).  It needs to find records in DNS to tell it who the PDC is.

Comment: OK I FIXED IT.. I aslo setup a reverse look up or whatever.

Comment: Glad this fixed your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your computer can't reach the default DNS servers, which are defined as:

```
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 107.7.59.210
                                       207.230.75.50
```

Change it so the DNS server is 192.168.52.183.

You might also want to edit your question to provide the correct answer for someone who happens to come across it.